Does OkHttp’s maxRequests/maxRequestsPerHost apply to synchronous requests?
Does OkHttp’s maxRequests/maxRequestsPerHost apply to synchronous/blocking requests? The documentation is not clear.
https://square.github.io/okhttp/5.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-dispatcher/index.html

No. There are no limits on synchronous requests.

Are there any practical limitations to synchronous requests? Is there another thread pool that is used to enforce, e.g., call timeouts?

More specifically, if using OkHttp for synchronous requests and there is high block wait time seen on okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner and okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection, what could cause that?

Oooh if you’re seeing any contention there, that’s a severe bug. Please open a new tracking bug with a thread dump if possible.

Maybe you’re running into this bug? https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/8388

Yes I think that bug is related to what I'm seeing. I'll see if I can post any supporting information in the GitHub issue. Thank you.
